# Wrong result after converting image from floating-point to unsigned in implementing JPEG

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, jpeg, image-compression

I have a problem with my code in implementing the JPEG compression using OpenCV and C++. On the encoder and after the code does the DCT when I add a line of code, which converts the planes from 32-bit floating-point to 8-bit unsigned, I get some weird output as you can see below. After this conversion, besides the fact that the result is not acceptable (cause I didn't even write the quantization part yet) even the original image is affected by this line of code. When changing this conversion to 16-bit unsigned, the original image is untouched and the decoded image becomes better, but the result is still not acceptable.

```
constexpr int blocksize = 8;

struct block {
    cv::Rect roi;
    cv::Mat subimage;
};

int main()
{
    //Reading the image and storing its necessary information
    std::string addr("C:\\Users\\lena.jpg");
    const cv::Mat img = cv::imread(addr, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    if (img.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open the image!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
}
int height = img.size().height;
int width = img.size().width;
std::cout << "width * height: " << width << " * " << height << std::endl;

//Constructing 8 by 8 blocks
std::vector<block> blocks;

for (int y = 0; y < height; y += blocksize){
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x += blocksize){
        int block_width = std::min(blocksize, width - x);
        int block_height = std::min(blocksize, height - y);
        block temp;
        cv::Rect newROI(x, y, block_width, block_height);
        temp.roi = newROI;
        temp.subimage = img(newROI);
        blocks.push_back(temp);
    }
}
//Discrete Cosine Transformation and Quantization
for (int bIdx = 0; bIdx < blocks.size(); ++bIdx) {
    std::vector<cv::Mat> planes;
    cv::split(blocks[bIdx].subimage, planes);

    std::vector<cv::Mat> resultPlanes(planes.size());
    for (int k = 0; k < planes.size(); ++k) {
        planes[k].convertTo(planes[k], CV_32FC1);

            cv::dct(planes[k], resultPlanes[k]);
            //The line that I mentioned above
            resultPlanes[k].convertTo(resultPlanes[k], CV_8UC1);
        }
        cv::merge(resultPlanes, blocks[bIdx].subimage);
}

//Inverse of DCT and Quantization
for (int bIdx = 0; bIdx < blocks.size(); ++bIdx) {
    std::vector<cv::Mat> planes;
    cv::split(blocks[bIdx].subimage, planes);

    std::vector<cv::Mat> resultPlanes(planes.size());
    for (int k = 0; k < planes.size(); ++k) {
        planes[k].convertTo(planes[k], CV_32FC1);
        cv::idct(planes[k], resultPlanes[k]);
        
        resultPlanes[k].convertTo(resultPlanes[k], CV_8UC1);
    }
    cv::merge(resultPlanes, blocks[bIdx].subimage);
}

//Reconstructing the whole image
cv::Mat modifiedImg = img.clone();
for (int bIdx = 0; bIdx < blocks.size(); ++bIdx) {
    blocks[bIdx].subimage.copyTo(modifiedImg(blocks[bIdx].roi));
}

//Show the result
cv::imshow("JPEG", img);
cv::imshow("My JPEG", modifiedImg);
cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not tag C for a question using C++ code and not C code.

Comment: How do you want to handle negative values which are generated by DCT on unsigned int types ? Try: CV_16S type when doing conversion from float to integer.

Comment: understand the values in `resultPlanes[k]` and what happens when you convert them to unsigned integers

Comment: @rafix07 yeah, I did that and it worked. But, our purpose at this stage is to minimize the space right? if I use CV_16S, it gets larger cause at the beginning it was an 8-bit image; and by the way, I can not understand why the original image changes when I convert it to 8-bit unsigned ...

Comment: After you quantize it no longer matters that it was 16S values, the output will have fewer bits. It is not the DCT that reduces size, it is that you can reduce size more after the DCT without too much perceptual loss.

Comment: I am puzzled by what you are trying to do by converting the data to 32-bit floating point. The input to the IDCT should be 16-bit integer, unless you have some custom procedure that does floating point. It appears that your library is working on your buffers in binary mode